# Automated export of a table/query from SQL SVR 2012 into Excel 2007 and subsequent VBA formatting macro?

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel, vba

I’ve been given the task of updating some code which isn’t working after our SQL SVR 200 to SQL SVR 2012 (don't laugh) conversion.  We have an automated task that creates 500ish xls files in a line-by-line manner by using the old sp_OACreate command.  In 2000, this job always takes hours and is rickety at best.  Needless to say, it doesn’t work at all in 2012.  That's what you get for never upgrading?

I rewrote the job by constructing a table, adding info into the table, & doing a bulk export into xls (using OpenRowSet).  The new task ran in less than 15 minutes and I was ecstatic.  Then Ops complained that the new files weren’t formatted…

I looped back and tried to get the formatting into the automation.  That’s where everything fell apart.

1. Use OpenRowSet and export into an “xls template file” that has an autorun vba code to do the formatting when the file is opened for the first time.  Didn’t work.
2. Use OpenRowSet and export into an “xlsm template file” that has an autorun vba code to do the formatting when the file is opened for the first time.  Didn’t work.
3. Use BCP and export into an “xls template file” that has an autorun vba code to do the formatting when the file is opened for the first time.  Didn’t work.
4. Use BCP and export into an “xlsm template file” that has an autorun vba code to do the formatting when the file is opened for the first time.  Didn’t work.
5. Use BCP/OpenRowSet and export into xls/xlsx and try to execute a vba code from another workbook…Didn’t work.
6. Use BCP/OpenRowSet, export into a “dummy” xls/xlsx, use a bat file to recopy the file, resave, etc…Didn’t work.
7. Use BCP/OpenRowSet, export into a “dummy” txt/csv, use a bat file to convert the file into excel, resave, etc…Didn’t work.
8. Etc.  Didn't work.

I tried every combination, every export method, every filetype, etc.  Certain methods allowed me to export but no formatting.  Other methods wouldn’t even export anything.  No method permitted the export/format, though.

Then I discovered the “REAL” problem ==> When I export using BCP/OpenRowSet and then try to open the file, I always get the “file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension” error (FYI Using Excel 2007).  I had sort of ignored this error, but after days of banging my head against the wall I can now see that this error was leading me to the real problem all along.  The export file (regardless of xls/xlsm/xlsx) is not an actual excel file; it’s really just a bunch of html tags.  This is why the formatting vba code won’t work; it’s not an actual excel file!  No matter what I do, it’s still not a real excel file.  Formatting will never work because it's simply not a real excel file.

So, I need an automated method to export a table to some sort of excel format (xls/xlsm/xlsx) and then execute a vba code to format (bold, column width, number/date formatting, etc.) the newly-exported file.  This seems like such a routine task…but I see now that routine <> easy.  I’ve seen references to NPOI and ClosedXML in forums, but I simply can’t believe that I need additional 3rd party software to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some VBA code in an Excel Spreadsheet to go get the data from your database and then do the formatting VBA after.  The below code should be a good starting point.

Please note that you will have to add a Reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library` for this code to function.  Also, you may need to change the Provider in you connection string deepening on you systems configuration.  The below code utilizes the SQL Server Native Client 11.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim SQLrs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLCommand As String

SQLCommand = "SELECT...FROM..."

cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=xxxxxxx;DataBase=xxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
cn.Open
cn.Execute "SET NOCOUNT ON" ''required for complex T-SQL queries

SQLrs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Call SQLrs.Open(SQLCommand, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic)

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset SQLrs

SQLrs.Close
Set SQLrs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, jradich1234.  Your solution is a little difficult to accomplish on this end simply because I've got 500 spreadsheets.  I'd have to get a loop where the SQL processed and then got the excel to do the import==> one at a time.  That seems cumbersome.

Comment: I suppose I could build an On_Open event into an xls-type and get it into the loop that way?  I dunno.  It seems like that will take forever and be a big rickety process like we already have...I guess it's time to go the third-party route.

Comment: My best advice would be to code something in a real object oriented coding environment.  At that point you could spin up worker threads to create multiple of what ever your output needs to be simultaneously.  That's going to be best combination of speed and custom tailored to meet your needs.